# changing window.beforeunload message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if can I change the `window.beforeunload` message.  All examples on the internet are similar to this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes. If you leave the page these changes will be lost.';
});
```

That's cool, and in Google Chrome my message will be displayed, but in Firefox the default message is displayed. How can i trick Firefox to display my message and not the default message?

Comment: Firefox (version 4+) doesn't support custom messages on `onbeforeunload` anymore.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292

Comment: @RocketHazmat you might want to add that as an answer. For points and whatnot. **Update:** I see you have 50k points, you probably already know how this works. Disregard.

Comment: @Felix: Sometimes when answers are just "you can't" or "that's how it works", I don't feel like typing an entire answer :-P  Alas, I added one anyway :-)

Comment: Chrome no longer displays the custom message returned from `beforeunload`. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onbeforeunload` is a weird event.  Browsers have been debating what to do with it for a while.

- IE and Chrome will display your message in the dialog along with their own message.
- Firefox used to display your message, but in version 4+, they stopped supporting custom messages. See this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292
- Opera doesn't even support the `onbeforeunload` method!

This method is under debate because it can be used for *evil*, and also because it can confuse/annoy users.  Scammy, virus-laden sites can use messages like:

> "Leaving the page will mean your computer may still be infected, please stay and install our virus scanner"

Nowadays, websites can use AJAX / localStorage to save changes, so this event isn't really needed.

Comment: but sometimes it's important to use that event suppose that you have like 10 hyperlink in the page where you r adding a new product and in the middle of adding that product you forget to save your work and click on some of those hyperlink and suppose that the add product form contain so many inputs to fill shouldn't u warn the user that wait stop you may loose your work ?

Comment: @Sora: Yes that fine, I was just pointing out that it could *also* be used for "other" purposes.  Also, that not all browsers even support the event.  You can use AJAX to save it as you type, so nothing is lost when you leave.  If you want to use the event, go for it, just know that each browser treats it differently.